# Absolute imports aren't working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, webpack, jsx

I have a ReactJS project called `my-app`, that was created using the `Redux+TS` template.

It's folder structure is like this:

```
node-modules
public
src/
    components/
        Controller.jsx
    App.jsx
    index.jsx
jsconfig.json
package-lock.json
package.json
```

**App.jsx:**

```js
import React from "react";
import Controller from "components/controller";
```

**jsonfig.json:**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I'm trying to import the `Controller` component into my `App` component using **absolute imports**, but whenever I compile it, I get an error:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR IN ./src/App.jsx

Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/Controller' in '<container-directory>\my-app\src
```

Comment: I saw that you are importing controller with the following way `import Controller from "components/controller"` instead that, try this `import Controller from "./components/Controller"`. and the project looks like you did not create with Redux+TS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply **Luis**. If I use `"./components/Controller"`  instead of `"components/controller"`, it works perfectly fine. I am looking for a way to be able to insert `"components/controller"` into any file in my project's `src` and it'll automatically know to link to `my-app/src/components/Controller`. In other words, an absolute import. Secondly, it doesn't look like I used Redux+TS because I replaced the tsconfig.json with jsconfig.json.